Incompatible Types: TZDate and TDateTime in Delphi 2010
I am trying to backport an app from Delphi CE 10.4 to Delphi 2010.  I am trying to use ZeosLib (8.0.0 stable) for the first time to connect to the SQLite database used with Delphi 10.4 CE, but keep getting this error:

Incompatible Types: TZDate and TDateTime

All other fields work without issue.
I have tried to google this issue, but cannot find any suggestions or help.  I have searched the ZeosLib Forum and no help there, either.
I want to convert a string to date, and used the standard:
DHTData.vitalsvdate.Value :=  StrToDate(edDate.text);

Is there a conversion I need to be doing/using with ZeosLib?

I found the way to make this work.  You have to include ZSysUtils, ZVariant, ZClasses, ZCompatibility in the uses section;
Then declare in variables part of the code:
 var
    ZDate :TZDate;
  begin
    Zdate :=  DHTData.bloodsugargdate.Value; //the value of edDate.text
    case button of
    ...
    //This "DHTData.vitalsvdate.Value :=  StrToDate(edDate.text);" becomes
    ...
    DHTData.vitalsvdate.Value :=  ZDate;  
  end

Source: Backporting App to Delphi 10.4: Encountering 'IncompatibleTypes: TZDate TDateTime' with ZeosLib

TZDate is defined as a record:
TZDate = packed record //keep it packed !!
  Year: Word;
  Month: Word;
  Day: Word;
  IsNegative: WordBool; //MySQL allows negative date values
end;

As such, you can't simply assign a TDateTime to it directly.
However, ZeosLib does have a DecodeDateTimeToDate() function in its ZSysUtils unit for converting a TDateTime into a TZDate:
procedure DecodeDateTimeToDate(const Value: TDateTime; var Date: TZDate);

There is also additional functions in the ZSysUtils unit for decoding a formatted string into a TZDate:
function TryRawToDate(Value: PAnsiChar; Len: Cardinal; const Format: String; var Date: TZDate): Boolean;
function TryUniToDate(Value: PWideChar; Len: Cardinal; const Format: String; var Date: TZDate): Boolean;
function TryPCharToDate(P: PAnsiChar; Len: Cardinal; const FormatSettings: TZClientFormatSettings; var Date: TZDate): Boolean; overload;
function TryPCharToDate(P: PWideChar; Len: Cardinal; const FormatSettings: TZClientFormatSettings; var Date: TZDate): Boolean; overload;


Where can I find a tutorial or documentation on ZSysUtils with code snippets?  Thanks

I have no clue. I found this by looking at ZeosLib's source code on GitHub: https://github.com/frones/ZeosLib
